# In shopify with laravel 9 the APP is not loading

Tags: laravel-9, shopify-app-bridge

I am using laravel in shopify for custom App development. Laravel => 9 package => laravel/ossiset

I have used this link to install:

`https://clickysoft.com/shopify-laravel-app-development/`
I have installed it successfully and i have notice some strange behaviour with the APP using with Specific URL.

When i logged into my shopify admin account the URL is:

`https://admin.shopify.com/store/[STORE NAME]/products?selectedView=all`
When i switch to App and click on my APP to load. It will stop and shows the URL:

`https://admin.shopify.com/store/[STORE NAME]/apps/[APP NAME]`
The App is working on this URL:

`https://[STORE NAME].myshopify.com/admin/apps/[APP NAME]`
Now, I want APP should work on this URL:

`https://admin.shopify.com`
As this APP is with Laravel It is using BLADE engine.

Hope any help me to find a solution. Thank you